# Add fields to ActiveRecord model dynamically in Rails 2.2.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I wanted to allow an administrative user to add a field to an ActiveRecord Model via an interface in the Rails app.  I believe the normal ActiveRecord::Migration code would be adequate for modifying the AR Model's table structure (something that would not be wise for many applications - I know).  Of course, only certain types of fields could be added...in theory.

Obviously, the forms that add (or edit) records to this newly modified ActiveRecord Model would need to be build dynamically at run-time.  A common form_for approach won't do.  This discussion suggests this can only be accomplished with JavaScript.

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/fc0b55fd4b2438a5

I've used Ruby in the past to query an object for it's available methods.  I seem to remember it was insanely slow.  I'm too green with Ruby and Rails to know an elegant way to approach this.  I hope someone here may.  I'm also open to entirely different approaches to this problem that don't involve modifying the database.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you require an administrative interface that dynamically adds _columns_ to misc. tables in the rails DB schema?

Comment: Yes, that is the thought.  Due to the flexibility of ActiveRecord, I figured it would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I wanted to allow an
>   administrative user to add a field to
>   an ActiveRecord Model via an interface
>   in the Rails app.

I've solved this sort of problem before by having an extra model called AdminAdditions. The table includes an id, an admin user id, a model name string, a type string, and a default value string.

I override the model's find and save methods to add attributes from its admin_additions, and save them appropriately when changed. The model table has a large text field, initially empty, where I save nondefault values of the added attributes.

Essentially the views and controllers can pretend that every attribute of the model has its own column. This means `form_for` and so on all work.

Answer (score 6):

To access the columns which are currently defined for a model, use the [columns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002239) method - it will give you, for each column, its name, type and other information (such as whether it is a primary key, etc.)

However, modifying the schema at runtime is delicate.

The schema is pre-loaded (and cached, from the DB driver) by each model class when it is first loaded.  In `production` mode, Rails only does this *once* per model, around startup.

1. In order to force Rails to refresh its cached schema following your modification, you should force Ruby to reload the affected model's class (pretty much what Rails does for you automatically, after each request, when running in `development` mode - see [how to reload a class using `remove_const` followed by `load`](http://hildolfur.wordpress.com/2006/10/29/class-reloading-in-ruby/).)
2. If you have a Mongrel cluster, you also have to inform the other processes in the cluster, which run in their own separate memory space, to also reload their model's classes (some clusters will allow you to create a 'restart.txt' file, which will cause an automatic soft-restart of all processes in your cluster with no additional work required on your behalf.)

Now, these having been said, depending on the actual problem that you need to solve you may not need to dynamically alter the schema after all.  Instead of adding, say, columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3` to some table `entries` (model `Entry`), you can use a table called `dyn_attribs`, where Entry `has_many :dyn_attribs`, and where `dyn_attribs` has both a `key` column (which in this case can have values `col1`, `col2` or `col3`) and a `value` column (which lists the corresponding values for `col1`, `col2` etc.)

Thus, instead of:

```
my_entry = Entry.find(123)
col1 = my_entry.col1
#do something with col1
```

you would use:

```
my_entry = Entry.find(123, :include => :dyn_attribs)
dyn_attribs = my_entry.dyn_attribs.inject(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) { |s,a|
  s[a.key] = a.value ; s
}
col1 = dyn_attribs[:col1]
#do something with col1
```

The above `inject` call can be factored away into the model, or even into a base class inherited from by all models that may require additional, dynamic columns/attributes (see [Polymorphic associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) on how to make several models share the same `dyn_attribs` table for dynamic attributes.)

---

**UPDATE**

Adding or renaming a column via a regular HTML form.

Assume that you have a `DynAttrTable` model representing a table with dynamic attributes, as well as a `DynAttrDef` defining the dynamic attribute names for a given table.

Run:

```
script/generate scaffold_resource DynAttrTable name:string
script/generate scaffold_resource DynAttrDef name:string
rake db:migrate
```

Then edit the generated models:

```
class DynAttrTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dyn_attr_defs
end

class DynAttrDef < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dyn_attr_table
end
```

You may continue to edit the controllers and the views [like in this tutorial](http://ariejan.net/2007/01/23/rails-nested-resource-scaffold/), replacing `Recipe` with `DynAttrTable`, and `Ingredient` with `DynAttrDef`.

**Alternatively**, use one of the plugins [reviewed here](http://www.joesniff.co.uk/critique/rails-admins-plugins-review.html) to automatically put the `dyn_attr_tables` and `dyn_attr_defs` tables under management by an automated interface (with all its bells and whistles), with virtually zero implementation effort on your behalf.

This should get you going.

Comment: This is an elegant approach to the problem on the back end. I'm concerned about browser support, so is there an easy way using pure HTML forms (no AJAX) generated by Ruby to build a form dynamically so it would include the new dynamic attributes automatically? Googling is not turning up an easy way

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column(User, "email", :string)

Comment: ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column(User, "email", :string);
User.reset_column_information

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Flex Attributes](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/flex_attributes) for this, though if you want to be able to search or order by these new columns you'll have to write (a lot of) custom SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the dynamic alteration/migration of tables offered as a solution many times but I have never actually seen it implemented. There are many reasons why this solution is rarely implemented.

- If the table is large then the table may/will be locked for extended periods of what is supposed to be up-time.
- Why is your model changing dynamically? It is quite rare for a models structure to need to change dynamically. It is more often an indication that you are trying to model something specific in a generalised way.
- This is often an attempt a producing a "Categorised" model than could be better solved by another approach.
- DDL statements are often not allowed by the same user that is being used for day to day DML requirements. Whilst this could be the case, and often is in the ROR arena it is not always the "right" way to do it.

What are you trying to achieve here? A better understanding of the problem would probably reveal a more natural solution.

Comment: My goal is to allow administrative users to add custom fields (of limited types) to specific (not all) models in the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you were doing this with PostgreSQL now you could probably get away with a JSON type field and then just store whatever in the json hash.